# QT Build Error ' Expected a platform name ' (Xcode 6.3.2 / OS X 10.10 / Qt 5.4.2)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt, qt5

**OS X 10.10, Xcode 6.3.2, Qt 5.4.2 clang 64bit**

After moving to Yosemite and QT 5 I can't build my C++ project on Mac anymore. 
I get the next errors after **clean,qmake and rebuild:**

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/unistd.h:185: error: expected a platform name, e.g., 'macosx'
int getattrlistbulk(int, void *, void *, size_t, uint64_t) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_10, __IPHONE_8_0);
                                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/unistd.h:203: error: expected a platform name, e.g., 'macosx'
int     faccessat(int, const char *, int, int) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_10, __IPHONE_8_0);
                                               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/gethostuuid.h:39: error: expected a platform name, e.g., 'macosx'
int gethostuuid(uuid_t, const struct timespec *) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_5, __IPHONE_NA);
                                                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/string.h:145: error: expected a platform name, e.g., 'macosx'
errno_t memset_s(void *, rsize_t, int, rsize_t) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_9, __IPHONE_7_0);
                                                ^
```

and a few more almost exact same errors...

If I just **build file .pro** I get:

`:-1: error: No rule to make target 'build/eTarApp.o'.  Stop.`

I've already tried all the solutions I could find to similar issues.

1. I reinstalled Xcode and the command line, but no success ([Link to forum](https://github.com/strongloop/fsevents/issues/40))
2. I specified the path to SDK 10.10 ( macosx10.10) in both .bash_profile and qdevice.pri file, and added `QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.9` in my  *.pro ([Link to forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/38440/help-getting-started-build-failure/11))
3. I've fixed all the errors that I got from transition from qt4 to qt5

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the code that triggers these errors?